# Windows 10 USB installer: screen glitching

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, display-driver, media-creation-tool

The HP TPN-C130 laptop of a friend of mine refuses to boot to Windows. He had already encountered some issues with the Windows 10 install on the laptop itself (mainly it being slow and crashing) and has attempted to run the in-built HP recovery software.

However this has further messed things up so that the laptop no longer successfully boots Windows: instead it will state (in Dutch) that ["recovery could not be completed", with the cmd window behind it stating that "the system could not find the given station (= disk)".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc6aP.jpg)

I figured that using a Windows 10 USB install drive (made with the MS Media Creation Tool) would do the trick instead, but I am running into issues there as well; after configuring the BIOS to **Disable SecureBoot** and **Enable Legacy Mode** I can finally boot from the USB itself, rather than it still going to Windows. [Although I first get the Windows 10 logo for a split second and it all looks OK, the screen then starts to glitch out as shown on the picture: Glitching out display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcX5Y.jpg)

I suspect this might be something with the display driver crashing, but I cannot figure out a workaround for it. It does not appear that the Win10 installer has a text-based mode, attaching an external display does not output anything and I have tried with 3 different USB devices already, all with the same outcome. Perhaps making a bootable USB through Rufus *might work*? I am also getting my external HDD dock tomorrow so I can wipe the drive remotely, would that give me results?

How can I best proceed with this?

Comment: Disabling Secure Boot is fine but makes no difference whatsoever (you aren't booting/installing Linux with proprietary drivers); enabling Legacy Mode is dumb and can only make things worse. All this is moot though because the hardware is defective, graphics and/or motherboard, and maybe the drive as well because that was the first symptom. And, of course, it doesn't matter how you're making the Windows installation media.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your input! The weird thing is that I was only able to make the USB bootable via disabling secure boot and enabling legacy mode, any other combo would mean that Windows booted, even after I modified the boot order in the BIOS and / or selected the USB device expressly for booting :S.
Whats even weirder is that this screen glitching malarky only shows up when attempting to install from USB, as you can see from the 1st linked picture the display works fine in all other circumstances. So weirdly it does not seem like the hardware is defective?

Comment: You have UEFI, not BIOS. The best way to boot external media is to use the one-time boot menu / Boot override features (one or both are usually present). If you're still thinking about "booting drives" instead of OS stanzas in a given EFI partition mistakes can and will happen. A USB made with the official tool boots in either mode, UEFI or Legacy/"BIOS". Not enabling CSM/Legacy/"BIOS" is the way to assure it boots -and- installs in the proper UEFI mode.

Comment: Good point, I have set back the UEFI + BIOS to their defaults, have set the boot delay to 5 seconds so I can get the F9 hotkey in. If I select USB Hard Drive (EUFI) I still get the glitched out screen, except now with with the HP logo instead of the Win10 setup logo. I want to reiterate that if I let it boot by itself (or use F9, then select Windows boot manager) that the screen stays OK and I get to the previously explained error inside Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your many inputs and insights :)

Ultimately what proved to be the issue was that I was trying to install the latest version of Windows 10, version 20H2. I have seen some computers that did not handle the update to this version well, but I never considered the fact that a clean install of this 20H2 version could be severely problematic as well.

Instead I used the Windows ISO Downloader from Heidoc to obtain the 1909 version of Windows 10, which I have installed without any issues. Again guys and gals thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple: you just have to wait. For me (AMD Ryzen 4700U) it was 1 minute.